# How to add Bearer {JWT} in swagger django?

Tags: django, swagger

when I authorize myself in Swagger UI, I have to write "Bearer {then I write JWT} here"

How can I add the string "Bearer" automatically before the JWT token in swagger UI?
Here is my Swagger Settings:

```
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    "SECURITY_DEFINITIONS": {
        "JWT [Bearer {JWT}]": {
            "name": "Authorization",
            "type": "apiKey",
            "in": "header",
        }
    },
    "USE_SESSION_AUTH": False,
}

FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = "/"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend you to migrate from `drf-yasg` to [`drf_spectacular`](https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html), it already includes JWT authentication automatically and without so many complications, it even uses [OpenAPI 3](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.1.0) (`drf-yasg` uses OpenAPI 2 and is becoming obsolete)

**Automatic Generation**

[image]

**Authenticate with JWT**

[image]

See this [From drf-yasg to OpenAPI 3](https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/drf_yasg.html)

Comment: Thank you! This was very nice and straightforward.

Comment: just a quick question, how do you set the `"ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(minutes=10), "REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=1)` ?

Comment: see [this](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#access-token-lifetime). 

`ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME`: Max time of the jwt after created.
`REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME`: Max time to refresh the token.

Answer (score -3):

Its only one solution simple add Bearer and space before paste the token in value field where you add token simple