# How to add prefix Bearer on django-yasg swagger

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, drf-yasg

I am using django-yasg swagger. And i need to add prefix Bearer before my token in authorization.Header needed for django-rest-framework: Bearer 
I should write only token, and it makes automatically into header Authorization.
My settings:

```
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
   'SECURITY_DEFINITIONS': {
      'Bearer': {
            'type': 'apiKey',
            'name': 'Authorization',
            'in': 'header'
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72149357/13478090.
This guy recommends the use of [drf-spetacular](https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), which already supports this by default, has an easier usage, plus uses [OpenAPI 3](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.1.0) when drf-yasg still uses 2 which will be soon deprecated.